# How to generate AWS CloudFormation template from an RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have created an AWS Aurora/PostgreSQL database using the console. I would like to generate a CloudFormation template from this RDS.

I tried using the CloudFormation Designer, but it does not appear to provide this functionality. Is there a way to generate the CloudFormation template from an existing RDS?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormer is the AWS tool for doing this

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html

Answer (score 0):

There is stack available in CloudFormation templates named CloudFormer. You can create AWS CloudFormation Templates from Existing AWS Resources by using this stack. Although, as it is in Beta version it might not be supported for all the resources. You can refer the document for more information about CloudFormer:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html